# Magento 2: Getting error after adding Adobe Sensei keys in the admin configuration

Tags: magento2.4, adobe-sensei

I'm getting the below error after adding Adobe Sensei sandbox and productions keys in the admin panel.

**"The API key you provided is not valid for use with Product Recommendations. Please use an API key that has Magento Commerce entitlements."**

Magento_ProductRecommendations extension was installed at the time of Magento installation.

Does anyone have any idea about this error? Please share the solution for this.

Thank you.